# Swift 4, device orientation

Tags: ios, swift, core-location, arkit

I'm doing a ArKit+CoreLocation app that when I touch a node I display some information on a View on the screen. Te problem is that when I rotate the device, I redraw the DataView but is not be drawing correctly.

The first thing I've noticed is that, when I launched the app, and the phone is in portrait mode, I have to evaluate `if(!UIDevice.current.orientation.isPortrait )` to get the right dimensions for that case. **Why during the launch the orientation is not portrait?**

Also the dimensions are managed well only on the application start. If I run the application during landscape mode, the view is rendered correctly, and the same case for portrait. Another problem that I've detected is that when I "redraw" the view, if I want to update the text inside the view, that is not longer possible.

I made a video to show you what is happening, also to know when a node is selected it has a purple circle around it. And you will see that after the reorientation, does not matter which node I touch, I can't update the text. 
https://youtu.be/ls_Y6dnW8E4

My source code is

```
/*
 * Initialize the TextView to display the information about the monument
 */
func initDataView() {

    let screenWidth = self.view.frame.width
    let screenHeight = self.view.frame.height
    var leftPadding : CGFloat = 0.0
    var bottomPadding : CGFloat = 0.0
    var frameHeight : CGFloat = 0.0

    /*
     * Configure paddings if the device is a phone
     */
    if (UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .phone) {

        if ( UIDevice.current.orientation.isPortrait ) {
            (leftPadding, bottomPadding, frameHeight) = getDataViewPaddings(phone: true, portrait: true, screenWidth: screenWidth, screenHeight: screenHeight)
        } else {
            (leftPadding, bottomPadding, frameHeight) = getDataViewPaddings(phone: true, portrait: false, screenWidth: screenWidth, screenHeight: screenHeight)
        }

    }

    dataView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: screenWidth-(leftPadding*2), height: screenHeight/frameHeight))
    dataView.frame.origin.x = leftPadding
    dataView.frame.origin.y = screenHeight - dataView.frame.height - bottomPadding
    //dataView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white.withAlphaComponent(0.7)

    //Adjust border and border color
    dataView.layer.borderWidth = 4.0
    dataView.layer.borderColor = UIColor(hexString: "#951789ff")?.cgColor

    initTextView(leftPadding: leftPadding)

    dataView.addSubview(textView)
    dataView.addSubview(descriptionView)
    dataView.addSubview(iconView)

}

public override func willTransition(to newCollection: UITraitCollection, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
    initDataView()
}
```

Comment: Check your target setting > General > Deployment Info. If Device orientation support landscape, it can be non portrait. FYI, you can use landscape mode even you uncheck landscape in the setting. The setting is for launch.

Answer (score 0):

Using UIKit UIViews with a ARkit ARSCNView is not different than with any other view.  If you are setting custom frames that code must be done in viewDidLayoutSubviews.  In this case though it looks like you want to just pin your view some distance from the leading edge and bottom with constant width and height.  If that's what you want then just use autolayout and let the layout engine calculate the position.  this works in code or interface builder.  You can manually set the class of a UIView to a ARSCNView in interface builder as well.